# Dropdown doesn't work when I include my header in another JSP

Tags: jsp

when I'm going to include a header.jsp into my other jsp pages The header possesses a dropdown menu, which is working when I load header.jsp But when I include the header into another JSP file, the dropdown menu doesn't work..Please suggest me how can i do that...

code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>



<html>
    <body>
        <header class="page-header" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">

            <img style="width: 100%" height="100px;" src="img/banner1.jpg">
        </header>



        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin: 0px;" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="home.jsp" title="The Official Start Bootstrap Blog"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="showmap.html">Map View</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">

                            <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Our Collection of Templates &amp;">Application Form <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="a.jsp">A</a></li>
                                <li><a href="b.jsp">B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="c.jsp">C</a></li>
                                <li><a href="d.jsp">D</a></li>


                            </ul>
                        </li>


                         <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                                <li><a href="applicationStatus.jsp">Application Status</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/contact" title="">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <a href="/help" title="">Help</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>




    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define not working. Show the code that doesn't work rather than the code that does work.

Comment: ok @AlanHay, if i use <jsp:include page="/header.jsp"></jsp:include> in other jsp dropdown is not display...